# Where else did Gildor see Bilbo?

Tags: the-lord-of-the-rings, tolkiens-legendarium

In The Fellowship of Ring book, Frodo, Sam and Pippin encounter a party of Elves in the woods of The Shire, led by Gildor Inglorion of the house of Finrod. The Elves invite the Hobbits to stay with them for the night after hearing of their pursuit by the Black Rider. They stay at their camp near the village of Woodhall, as the Elves rest before continuing their journey westwards towards the Grey Havens.

Frodo asks Gildor if he had seen Bilbo since he had left The Shire:

> Gildor smiled. 'Yes,' he answered. 'Twice. He said farewell to us on
>   this very spot. But I saw him once again, far from here.' He would say
>   no more about Bilbo, and Frodo fell silent.

From Chapter Three, *Three Is Company.*

I have always been a little unclear about this line. Where and when did this other meeting take place? Was it in Rivendell?

Comment: Rivendale, since thats were Bilbo was currently living, its vague because while gandalf and the elves already knew it appears bilbo wanted it a surprise.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

### Tolkien never specified

Most fans assume that the second meeting occurred at (or around) Rivendell, since this is where Gildor normally lives, as Tolkien writes in *The Road Goes Ever On* (recorded in *Reader's Companion*):

> [S]ince they appear to have been going eastward, [they] were Elves living in or near Rivendell returning from the *palantír* of the Tower Hills.
>
> <sup>*The Lord of the Rings: A Reader's Companion* Book I Chapter 3: "Three is Company"</sup>

However, none of Tolkien's writings are explicit on this point; Rivendell is the most sensible assumption but, since Bilbo is known to have travelled widely after the Party, they could have met just about anywhere in Middle-earth.